# Passing an IBaction to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-4.3

I have an IBAction button in one UIViewController that I want to perform an action in another UIViewController. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a method in the second UIViewController and call from the IBAction in the first controller.

Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)myMethodFromFirstController{

SecondController *secondController = [[SecondController alloc] init];
[secondController method];
```

}

Comment: How would the method look like in second view controller?

Comment: I am getting an error no visible interface: -(IBAction)myMethodFromFirstController{
    
    PhoneMainV *secondController = [[PhoneMainV alloc] init];
    [secondController myMethodFromFirstController];
}

Comment: I think you need to read about the basics of viewcontrollers, i recommend the big nerd ranch guide. Anyways, you can get a full tutorial from here. http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-how-to-set-the-view-and-how-to-switch-between-2-views.191002/